# Divide wordpress page into five columns

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create wordpress footer. I need to divide the page into five columns, I used two URL's as an example. I wrote the code as follows:

```css
    .footer-titlesb {
      color: #393939;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: left;
      line-height: 2.3;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    .lefttextb {
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 13px;
      color: #393939;
      !important;
      line-height: 1.8;
      font-weight: 400;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .lefttextb a {
      color: #393939;
    }
    .lefttextb a:hover {
      color: #393939;
      padding-bottom: 2px;
      border-bottom: 1px dashed #393939;
    }
```

```html
<div style="width: 20%; padding: 0 10px 0 0; float: left;">
  <div class="footer-titlesb">Our Community</div>
  <div class="lefttextb"><a href="http://domain.com/forums/">Forums</a>
    <br />
    <a href="http://domain.com/community">Community</a> 
    <br />Report a Problem
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 20%; padding: 0 10px 0 0; float: left;">
  <div class="footer-titlesb">Company</div>
  <div class="lefttextb">About Us
    <br />Privacy Policy
    <br />Terms
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 20%; padding: 0 10px 0 0; float: left;">
  <div class="footer-titlesb">Resources</div>
  <div class="lefttextb">Scores
    <br />Tips
    <br />Examination
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 20%; padding: 0 10px 0 0; float: left;">
  <div class="footer-titlesb">Follow Us</div>
  <div class="lefttextb">Facebook
    <br />Twitter
    <br />Google Plus
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 20%; padding: 0 10px 0 0; float: right;">
  <div class="footer-titlesb">Connect</div>
  <div class="lefttextb">Contact Us
    <br />Feedback
    <br />Send us
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="”clear: both;"></div>
```

I am not sure why the columns don't go in one line. I would be glad if you correct me as I am afraid I have a problem with the float (i.e: left, right, etc...) or it might be I am using different width.

Comment: Please go through all of the questions you've asked here, and select a "correct" answer where you've found one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`box-sizing` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to alter the default CSS box model used to calculate widths of elements. Currently, the padding on each div is causing the effective width of each div to be `10px + 20%`.

You can change `box-sizing` to `border-box` to remedy this:

```css
    .footer-titlesb {
      color: #393939;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: left;
      line-height: 2.3;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    .lefttextb {
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 13px;
      color: #393939;
      !important;
      line-height: 1.8;
      font-weight: 400;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .lefttextb a {
      color: #393939;
    }
    .lefttextb a:hover {
      color: #393939;
      padding-bottom: 2px;
      border-bottom: 1px dashed #393939;
    }
```

```html
<div style="width: 20%; padding: 0 10px 0 0; float: left; box-sizing: border-box;">
  <div class="footer-titlesb">Our Community</div>
  <div class="lefttextb"><a href="http://domain.com/forums/">Forums</a>
    <br />
    <a href="http://domain.com/community">Community</a> 
    <br />Report a Problem
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 20%; padding: 0 10px 0 0; float: left; box-sizing: border-box;">
  <div class="footer-titlesb">Company</div>
  <div class="lefttextb">About Us
    <br />Privacy Policy
    <br />Terms
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 20%; padding: 0 10px 0 0; float: left; box-sizing: border-box;">
  <div class="footer-titlesb">Resources</div>
  <div class="lefttextb">Scores
    <br />Tips
    <br />Examination
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 20%; padding: 0 10px 0 0; float: left; box-sizing: border-box;">
  <div class="footer-titlesb">Follow Us</div>
  <div class="lefttextb">Facebook
    <br />Twitter
    <br />Google Plus
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 20%; padding: 0 10px 0 0; float: right; box-sizing: border-box;">
  <div class="footer-titlesb">Connect</div>
  <div class="lefttextb">Contact Us
    <br />Feedback
    <br />Send us
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: To avoid line break on `Our Community`, you could also add; `.footer-titlesb { white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }`